# How to query GtkSettings from the command line?

Tags: gtk3

In particular I want to find the gtk-xft-dpi for my laptop (there is only one screen), without having to write a program for it.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious, but I could only find the settings in the [API definition here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-xft-dpi).

Answer (score 0):

Define "writing a program." You can do it with a Python one-liner from the command line:

```
python -c 'from gi.repository import Gtk; print(Gtk.Settings.get_default().props.gtk_xft_dpi)'
```

Although this is likely to print "-1" as that's the default value for that setting, meaning "use the default DPI, whatever that is."